# inkscape extension - covert use node to path node

Tags: svg, lxml, inkscape

recently i learned [how to combine svg elements into a combined path using inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131847/inkscape-combine-svg-elements-into-combined-path) and would now like to do it programmatically, but cannot reason how to do it with the inkscape api, `inkex`.

my document has `<use />` elements, which in inkscape 1.x show as path entities with the path tool, so, i figured i'd first try and just coerce the use into a path:

`if el.TAG == 'use': self.svg.replace(el, el.to_path_element())`

but inside of `elements.py`, on the to_path_element call, it throws with `AttributeError: Can't find attribute Use.path`.

anyone have ideas on how to convert `<use />` to `<path />` programatically?

question ported from: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132243/inkscape-extension-covert-use-node-to-path-node

Comment: The use element does not have an attribute named path. What about trying href instead?

Additionally, have you checked the API documentation? Search for 'class Use(' here: https://inkscape.gitlab.io/extensions/documentation/_modules/inkex/elements.html to get everything you need for the current Inkscape 1.0beta. It will not work with any released Inkscape versions though.

Comment: thx @Moini. indeed, i had seen some of that content, but wasn't sure how to proceed.  i did some further inspecting.  attribs['href'] is defined on the `Use` instance, but the actual href attribute is None.  my svg has a href attribute.  i tried using xlink:href, but it erroneously crashes with `Unable to open 'parser.pxi': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (/.../src/lxml/parser.pxi)).`--i'm pretty sure that's just bad error handling in library space, as the attr is the only diff. here's the svg i'm parsing: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/1d1d75586a61b4f4b90cb55c635eb972